# How to use GROUP BY in Django without using values()?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm, django-annotate

I am trying to GROUP BY with Django ORM:

```
sub = (
        Participant.objects
        .values('category')
        .annotate(
            average=Avg(F('price')),
        )
    )
```

It works as expected BUT the queryset does not contains instances of the model anymore. If contains `dicts` because `values()` has been called.

How can do a group by query and get a regular queryset (with model instances)?

Comment: Are you trying to get the average price per category or per participant?